# O que é um daemon?

Tags: convenções-de-nome

Sei que “demônio” vêm do latim *daemon*, mas acredito que essa palavra tem outro significado no meio tecnológico.

O que é um daemon? O que come? Para que serve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Etimologia da palavra daemon:

Em um documento da [Virginia Tech/Norfolk State University](https://ei.cs.vt.edu/) intitulado [The Origin of the word Daemon](https://ei.cs.vt.edu/%7Ehistory/Daemon.html) se encontra a explicação para a origem da palavra "daemon":

> Escrevo uma coluna de curiosidades para um jornal chamado The Austin
> Chronicle. Alguém me perguntou a origem da palavra daemon no que se
> refere à computação. O melhor que posso dizer com base em minha
> pesquisa é que a palavra foi usada pela primeira vez por pessoas de
> sua equipe no Projeto MAC usando o IBM 7094 em 1963. O primeiro daemon
> (uma abreviação de Disk And Executive MONitor) era um programa que
> fazia backups em fita automaticamente o sistema de arquivos.
>
> <sup>Richard Steinberg do jornal The Austin Chronicle</sup>

> Sua explicação sobre a origem da palavra daemon está correta, pois meu
> grupo começou a usar o termo por volta desse período. No entanto, a
> explicação da sigla é nova para mim. Nosso uso da palavra daemon foi
> inspirado no daemon da física e da termodinâmica de Maxwell. (Minha
> formação é física). O daemon de Maxwell era um agente imaginário que
> ajudava a classificar moléculas de diferentes velocidades e trabalhava
> incansavelmente em segundo plano. Fantasiosamente, começamos a usar a
> palavra daemon para descrever processos em segundo plano que
> trabalhavam incansavelmente para realizar tarefas do sistema.
> Encontrei uma explicação muito boa sobre tudo isso online em:
>
> http://www.takeourword.com/TOW129/page2.html (Pesquise em "Maxwell"
> para localizar o parágrafo pertinente.)
>
> <sup>Fernando J. Corbato engenheiro do projeto MAC</sup>

> [Aviso: este parágrafo é sobre ciência, portanto, se este tópico lhe
> causar um alarme indevido, feche os olhos até terminar de lê-lo.] O
> cientista do século 19 James Maxwell uma vez sonhou acordado (o termo
> educado é "experimento mental") sobre um problema de física. Ele
> imaginou um recipiente fechado dividido ao meio. No meio da divisória
> havia um pequeno portão, grande o suficiente apenas para admitir uma
> molécula de gás. Este portão, na imaginação de Maxwell, era operado
> por um pequeno daemon. Este daemon observou a velocidade (isto é,
> temperatura) das moléculas que se dirigiam para o portão e, dependendo
> da velocidade, as deixou passar. Se ele deixasse apenas as moléculas
> lentas passarem do lado A para o lado B e apenas as moléculas rápidas
> passassem do lado B para o lado A, então A ficaria quente enquanto B
> esfriava.  O daemon de Maxwell era apenas imaginário, é claro, mas
> como parecia escapar das leis da termodinâmica, causou um grande
> rebuliço. No final das contas, porém, a teoria da mecânica quântica
> mostrou por que ela não funcionaria. [OK, você pode abrir os olhos,
> agora.]
>
> Como você provavelmente sabe, os "processos do sistema" chamados
> daemons monitoram outras tarefas e executam ações predeterminadas
> dependendo de seu comportamento. Isso lembra tanto o daemon de Maxwell
> observando suas moléculas que só podemos presumir que quem quer que
> tenha apelidado esses "processos do sistema" tinha o daemon de Maxwell
> em mente. Nossa suposição foi confirmada para nós diretamente pelos
> professores Corbato e Saltzer, que trabalharam em um projeto de
> desenvolvimento de sistema no MIT em 1963 conhecido como Projeto MAC.
> Eles e os membros de sua equipe usaram o daemon pela primeira vez
> neste sentido naquela época, baseando-se no daemon de Maxwell.
>
> <sup>Paragrafo do [www.takeourword.com](http://www.takeourword.com/TOW129/page2.html) citado acima por Fernando J. Corbato.</sup>

## Descrição:

Da [Wikpédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)):

Em sistemas operacionais multitarefa, um daemon é um programa de computador que executa como um processo em plano de fundo, em vez de estar sob o controle direto de um usuário interativo. Tradicionalmente, o nome de processo de um daemon termina com a letra d, para deixar claro que o processo é, de fato, um daemon, e para diferenciação entre um daemon e um programa de computador normal. Por exemplo, syslogd é o daemon que implementa o recurso de logging do sistema e sshd é um daemon que serve conexões SSH de entrada.

Do [linux man-pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/daemon.7.html):

Um daemon é um processo de serviço executado em segundo plano e supervisiona o sistema ou fornece funcionalidade a outros processos. Tradicionalmente, os daemons são implementados seguindo um esquema originado em [SysV Unix](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V).     Daemons modernos devem seguir um esquema mais simples, porém mais poderoso(aqui chamado de daemons modernos), conforme implementado pelo [systemd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemd.1.html).

## Inicialização:

**SysV Daemons(estilo antigo)**: (Extraido do [linux man-pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/daemon.7.html))

Quando um daemon SysV tradicional é iniciado, ele deve executar o as etapas a seguir como parte da inicialização. Observe que estas etapas são desnecessárias para daemons de novo estilo (veja abaixo), e só deve ser implementado se a compatibilidade com SysV for     essencial.

1. Fecha todos os descritores de arquivo abertos, exceto a entrada padrão, saída e erro (ou seja, os três primeiros descritores de arquivo 0, 1, 2). Isso garante que nenhum o descritor de arquivo seja passado acidentalmente para o processo do daemon. No Linux, este é melhor implementado iterando por meio de `/proc/self/fd`, com um fallback da iteração do descritor de arquivo 3 para o valor retornado por `getrlimit()` para `RLIMIT_NOFILE`.
2. Redefine todos os manipuladores de sinais para seus padrões. Isso é melhor feito iterando através dos sinais disponíveis até o limite de `NSIG` e redefinindo-os para `SIG_DFL`.
3. Reinicializa a máscara de sinal usando `sigprocmask()`.
4. Higieniza o ambiente, removendo ou redefinindo variáveis ​​de ambiente que podem impactar negativamente o daemon tempo de execução.
5. Chama `fork()` para criar um processo em segundo plano.
6. No processo filho, chama `setsid()` para separar de qualquer terminal e criar uma sessão independente.
7. No processo filho, chama `fork()` novamente, para garantir que o daemon nunca podssa readquirir um terminal novamente. (Isso é relevante se o programa,e todas as suas dependências, não cuidadosamente especifique `O_NOCTTY` em cada chamada `open()` que pode potencialmente abrir um nó de dispositivo TTY.)
8. Chama `exit()` no primeiro filho, de modo que apenas o segundo filho (o processo daemon real) permanece. Isso garante que o processo daemon é redirecionado para `init/PID1`, como todos daemons deveriam ser.
9. No processo daemon, conecta a `/dev/null' à entrada padrão, saída e erro.
10. No processo daemon, redefine o `umask` para 0, para que o arquivo modos passados ​​para `open()`, `mkdir()` e similares controlem diretamente o modo de acesso dos arquivos e diretórios criados.
11. No processo daemon, altera o diretório atual para o diretório raiz (`/`), a fim de evitar que o daemon impeça que os pontos de montagem sejam desmontados involuntariamente.
12. No processo do daemon, escreve o PID do daemon (conforme retornado por `getpid()`) para um arquivo PID, por exemplo `/run/foobar.pid`(para um  daemon hipotético "foobar") para garantir que o daemon não possa ser iniciado mais de uma vez. Isso deve ser implementado em maneira livre de condições de corrida, de modo que o arquivo PID só é atualizado quando é verificado ao mesmo tempo que o PID previamente armazenado no arquivo PID não exista mais ou pertenç a um processo estrangeiro.
13. No processo daemon, cancela os privilégios possível e aplicável.
14. A partir do processo daemon, notifica o processo original iniciado que a inicialização está completa. Isso pode ser implementado via um pipe anônimo ou canal de comunicação similar que é criado antes do primeiro `fork()` e, portanto, disponível em ambos processos, o original e daemon.
15. Chame `exit()` no processo original. O processo que invocou o daemon deve ser capaz de assegurar que este `exit()` aconteça após a inicialização ser concluída e todos os canais de comunicação foram estabelecidos e estão acessíveis.

**Daemons modernos:** (Extraido do [linux man-pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/daemon.7.html))

Serviços modernos para Linux devem ser implementados como um novo estilo de daemons. Isso torna mais fácil supervisioná-los e controlá-los em tempo de execução e simplifica sua implementação.
Para desenvolver um daemon de novo estilo, nenhuma das etapas de inicialização das etapas recomendadas para daemons SysV precisam ser implementadas. Os novos sistemas de inicialização como o systemd tornam todos eles redundante. Além disso, uma vez que algumas dessas etapas interferem com monitoramento de processo, passagem de descritor de arquivo e outras funcionalidade do sistema de inicialização, é recomendado não os executar quando rodando com um serviço moderno.

Observe que os sistemas de inicialização modernos garantem a execução de processos daemon em um contexto de processo limpo, que é garantir que o ambiente é higienizado, que os manipuladores de sinal e máscara sejam redefinido e nenhuma sobra de descritor de arquivo restante seja passada.
Daemons serão executados em sua própria sessão, com entrada padrão conectada a `/dev/null` e  saida/erro padrão and standard output/error connected /dev/null e saída padrão / erro conectada ao serviço de registro [`systemd-journald.service()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-journald.service.8.html), a menos que configurada de outra forma. O `umask` é redefinido.

É recomendado para daemons de modernos implementar o que se segue:

1. Se `SIGTERM` for recebido, encerre o daemon e saia de forma limpa.
2. Se `SIGHUP` for recebido, recarregue os arquivos de configuração, se isto se aplicar.
3. Forneça um código de saída correto do processo daemon principal, como isso é usado pelo sistema init para detectar erros de serviço e problemas. Recomenda-se seguir o esquema de código de saída como definido nas recomendações LSB para scripts de inicialização SysV.
4. Se possível e aplicável, exponha a interface de controle do daemon através do sistema IPC D-Bus e pegue um nome de barramento como última etapa da inicialização.
5. Para integração no `systemd`, forneça um arquivo de unidade `a.service` que           carrega informações sobre como iniciar, parar e utilizar o daemon. Veja [systemd.service](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.service.5.html) para detalhes.
6. Tanto quanto possível, conte com a funcionalidade do sistema de inicialização           para limitar o acesso do daemon a arquivos, serviços e outros recursos, ou seja no caso do `systemd`, que dependem de controle de limite de recursos do `systemd` em vez de implementar seu próprio, conte com o privilégio de descartar o código do `systemd` em vez de implementá-lo no daemon e semelhantes. Ver [systemd.exec()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.exec.5.html) para os controles disponíveis.
7. Se o D-Bus for usado, torne seu daemon ativável por barramento fornecendo um arquivo de configuração de ativação do serviço D-Bus. Esta abordagem tem várias vantagens: seu daemon pode ter inicialização adiada.
   Sob demanda pode ser iniciado em paralelo com outros daemons o que maximiza a paralelização e a velocidade do boot.
   Rapidez, seu daemon pode ser reiniciado em caso de falha sem perder quaisquer solicitações do barramento, pois o barramento enfileira solicitações para serviços ativáveis.
8. Se o seu daemon fornecer serviços para outros processos locais ou clientes remotos através de um soket, deve ser feito como socket-ativável seguindo o esquema indicado abaixo.
   Como a ativação do D-Bus, isso permite o início sob demanda de serviços, bem como permite melhor paralelização de inicialização do serviço. Além disso, para protocolos sem estado (como *syslog*, *DNS*), um daemon que implementa ativação baseada em soket pode ser reiniciado sem perder uma única solicitação.
9. Se aplicável, um daemon deve notificar o sistema de inicialização sobre conclusão da inicialização ou atualizações de status via interface [sd_notify(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sd_notify.3.html).
10. Em vez de usar a chamada `syslog()` para registrar diretamente no serviço de `syslog` do sistema, um daemon moderno pode escolher simplesmente registrar o erro padrão via `fprintf()`, que é então é encaminhado ao `syslog` pelo sistema de inicialização. Se os níveis de registro forem necessário, eles podem ser codificados prefixando log individual           linhas com strings como `"<4>"`(para log de nível 4 "AVISO" em esquema de prioridade do `syslog`), seguindo um estilo semelhante a chamada do Kernel Linux `printk()` a nivel de sistema. Para detalhes, veja [`sd-daemon()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sd-daemon.3.html) e [`systemd.exec()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.exec.5.html).
11. Como daemons modernos são chamados sem um *TTY* de controle(mas como seus próprios encabeçadores de sessão) deve-se tomar cuidado para sempre especifique `O_NOCTTY` em chamadas `open()` que possivelmente referenciar um nó de dispositivo *TTY*, de modo que nenhum *TTY* de controle seja adquirido acidentalmente.

As recomendações são similares mas não idênticas aos [Requisitos Apple MacOS x Daemon](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

## Noutros sistemas operacionais:

**Microsoft DOS TSR**: [Trecho da Wikpédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminate_and_stay_resident_program)

Um programa terminate-and-stay-resident(geralmente TSR) é um programa de computador executado no DOS que usa uma chamada de sistema para retornar o controle ao DOS como se tivesse terminado, mas permanece na memória do computador para que possa ser reativado posteriormente. Essa técnica superou parcialmente a limitação do DOS de executar apenas um programa ou tarefa por vez. Os TSRs são usados ​​apenas no DOS, não no Windows.

Embora muito úteis, ou mesmo essenciais para superar as limitações do DOS , os TSRs têm a reputação de criadores de problemas. Muitos sequestram o sistema operacional de várias maneiras documentadas ou não documentadas, muitas vezes fazendo com que os sistemas travem na ativação ou desativação quando usados ​​com aplicativos específicos ou outros TSRs. Alguns vírus e outros malwares foram codificados como TSRs e são deliberadamente problemáticos. Além disso, no DOS todos os programas, mesmo aqueles com grande quantidade de RAM física , devem ser carregados nos primeiros 640  KB de RAM (a memória convencional) e os TSRs não são exceção e pegam pedaços desses 640 KB que, portanto, não estão disponíveis para outros aplicativos.

**Microsoft Windows Services**: (Trecho da [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service))

Nos sistemas operacionais Windows NT, um Windows Service(Ou Serviço Windows) é um programa de computador que opera em segundo plano. É semelhante em conceito a um daemon Unix.
Um serviço do Windows deve estar em conformidade com as regras de interface e protocolos do Service Control Manager, o componente responsável por gerenciar os serviços do Windows. É o aplicativo Services and Controller, services.exe, que lança todos os serviços e gerencia suas ações, como iniciar, terminar, etc.

Os serviços do Windows podem ser configurados para iniciar quando o sistema operacional for iniciado e rodar em segundo plano enquanto o Windows estiver em execução. Alternativamente, eles podem ser iniciados manualmente ou por um evento.
Os sistemas operacionais Windows NT incluem vários serviços executados no contexto de três contas de usuário: *Sistema*, *Serviço de Rede* e *Serviço Local*. Esses componentes do Windows são frequentemente associados ao Processo de Host para Serviços do Windows.
Como os serviços do Windows operam no contexto de suas próprias contas de usuário dedicadas, eles podem operar quando um usuário não está conectado.

Antes do Windows Vista , os serviços instalados como um "serviço interativo" podiam interagir com a área de trabalho do Windows e mostrar uma interface gráfica do usuário . No Windows Vista, entretanto, os serviços interativos estão obsoletos e podem não funcionar corretamente, como resultado da proteção do Windows Service.

Answer (score 2):

Daemon é um processo que roda no background de um sistema operacional. Basicamente, ele fica esperando requisições que serão feitas ao sistema, através do usuário, e trata dessas requisições para que elas possam ser atendidas. Ele atende não só requisições vindas do usuário, mas também dos mais diversos processos que precisam ficar rodando o tempo inteiro no background do sistema também, como indexamento de arquivos, atualizações de software, compressão de dados, web server,ssh server, dentre vários outros serviços.

Answer (score 1):

É o equivalente a um "serviço" do Windows, um programa que roda em segundo plano.

Entrando um pouco nos detalhes técnicos, um daemon

a) possui PGID (grupo de processos) exclusivo, só seu

b) possui SID (session id, uma espécie de grupo de grupos de processos) exclusivo só seu

c) não há um terminal controlador ligado a ele

Tudo isso para que o processo rode da forma mais isolada e previsível possível, sem que seu comportamento seja influenciado pelo que acontece no resto da máquina.

Quando um daemon é iniciado, é recomendado executar uma sequência de comandos para que, além do PGID e SID, o processo "esqueça" também outros parâmetros (umask, chdir) que ele de outra forma poderia herdar do processo-pai original : http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html